# Is Plato's Callicles an example of Nietzsche's Übermensch? Is the Epicurean hedonist?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, plato, pain-and-pleasure, scepticism

Is the hard-headed [Callicles from Plato's dialogue Gorgias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callicles) the type of person who exemplifies Nietzsche's Übermensch (overman)? What about the [hedonistic sage of Epicureans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_(philosophy)#In_Epicureanism?)? Is he a Übermensch?

Comment: Callicles is indeed hedonistic (see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/callicles-thrasymachus/#Call), point 5), but the hedonistic sage is not Nietzsche's over-human.

Comment: Also, it seems that some apparent similarities between Callicles' and Nietzsche's thoughts [are spurious](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/96849/64708) and a result of the usual caricature of Nietzsche's work. However, I am myself an amateur so for now cannot provide further insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in some ways Callicles comes close. One easily recognizes some of the key themes of [Nietzsche's master morality](http://www.kritike.org/journal/issue_8/urstad_december2010.pdf) there: the strong dominate the weak by nature, laws protecting the weak are unfair to the strong, morality is not established by gods but by men with their own petty interests, etc. According to [Urstad's Nietzsche and Callicles on Happiness, Pleasure, and Power](http://www.kritike.org/journal/issue_8/urstad_december2010.pdf):

> "*Although  there  is  no  mention  of  him  in  his  published  works,  there  is little  doubt  that  some  of  Nietzsche’s  most  famous  doctrines  were inspired  by  the  views  expressed  by  the  character  Callicles  in  Plato’s Gorgias*".

However, we should be careful with transplanting concepts across centuries and philosophical systems, especially as heterogenous as Nietzsche’s and Plato's, or we will end up, like some commentators, with Plato's Republic as a Marxist manifesto. There is more rational "Realpolitik" in Callicles than Zarathustra's Dionysian passion and exaltation.

As for hedonism, that is cold, very. In Nietzsche's picture hedonism is a sign of decadence. "*An overman as described by Zarathustra, the main character in Thus Spoke Zarathustra, is the one who is willing to risk all for the sake of enhancement of humanity. In contrast to the "last man" whose sole desire is his own comfort and who is incapable of creating anything beyond oneself in any form*", see [Nietzsche's Idea of an Overman and Life from His Point of View](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~pj97/Nietzsche.htm). If a hedonist is Nietzsche’s anything it would be the last man, not the Übermensch. Urstad concurs:

> "*Nietzsche clearly rails against the pursuit of pleasure where pleasure is 
>   understood  as  a  particular  sensation  marked  by  the  absence  of  any  pain  or discomfort.  He,  for  instance,  describes  Epicurus,  who  conceived  of  pleasure (ataraxia) as the absence of all physical and mental discomfort, as “representing a  state  in  which  one  is  neither  sick  nor  well,  neither  alive  nor  dead”... For Nietzsche, pleasure cannot be divorced from pain, rather, they are “twins”, in so far as one cannot have one  without  the  other.  He  states  that  pleasure  and  pain  are  “so  knotted together that whoever wants as much as possible of the one, must also have as much as possible of the other...”*"

Answer (score 1):

yes, we may say that because Calliclus say "Nature, he says, separates people into two kinds: the naturally superior
and dominant, and the naturally inferior, who can gain dominance only by
restraining the naturally superior people by means of laws and conventions.
Nature smiles upon the man who is able to defend himself against all comers;
this man is fit by nature to dominate inferior persons (483c–e), taking what of
theirs he desires without payment and with impunity, as Heracles drove off
Geryon’s cattle (484a–c). This is why conventional ideas about justice are
wickedly mistaken: the run of common people subvert the natural order and
establish laws and norms which would keep superior men from asserting their
natural right to dominate (483b–e). This natural order, Callicles says, is true
justice, not the sham justice of common lawmakers and moralists.

and Hence the ideal person must not restrict or curb these desires,
for to do so would be to succumb to the inauthentic, unnatural values embraced
by common people; rather, he must pursue self-indulgence with impunity, as a
dictator (491d–492c).

Comment: On [page 75](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Plato%27s_Gorgias_Literally_Translated_%28Cope%2C_1864%29.pdf) (491) *Soc.*: I mean that every man is his own governor. ... *Cal.*: What do you mean by governing one's own self? — Evidently Callicles isn't fit to govern anything, but I don't think Nietzsche meant the Superman to be so wanton, (although may have meant ruthless).  So Callicles is similar but different;  unqualified.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callicles) quote:

> Callicles argues the position of an oligarchic amoralist, stating that
> it is natural and just for the strong to dominate the weak ...

and from the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/callicles-thrasymachus/#Call)

> Callicles has said that nature reveals that it is just for the
> ‘superior’, ‘better’ or ‘stronger’ to have more: ...

Callicles sounds rather callous.  This is nothing like Nietzsche's overman, described [here](https://archive.org/stream/ApolloHumanRightsBooks/26585615-Heidegger-Martin-Off-the-Beaten-Track_djvu.txt) (Off the Beaten Track, page 189) by Heidegger.

> It is easy but irresponsible to be outraged by the idea and the figure
> of the overman, which was designed to be misunderstood; it is easy but
> irresponsible to pretend that one's outrage is a refutation. It is
> difficult  but for future thinking unavoidable ***to attain the high
> responsibility*** out of  which Nietzsche reflected on the essence of
> that humanity destined (in the  destiny of being as the will to power)
> to undertake mastery over the earth.
> **The essence of the overman is not a warrant for a fit of capricious frenzy.**  It is the law, grounded in being itself, of a long chain of
> the highest self-  overcomings, which alone will make man ripe for
> beings which as beings  are part of being.

(My emphasis.)  Taking the point of view that human beings are responsible for their own determinations of reality is no invitation to immoralistic vandalism.

Comment: +1 I emailed [FNS](https://www.fns.org.uk/) because I had a related question, and they told me to be careful because scholars that couple Callicles with Nietzsche are usually his detractors, since they don't have a proper understanding of Nietzsche' complex metaphysical Will to Power details.

Comment: I should have said *ontological* instead of *metaphysical*, I am still a neophyte and get easily confused by philosophical categories.

Comment: @irecorsan A partial reading of [Heidegger in Ruins](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0BSWRMFMT/) has made me rethink my opinion.  Heidegger may say "... not a warrant for a fit of capricious frenzy" but what he means by "It is the law" may well align with Callicles.

Comment: I personally cannot say because I am just starting to get familiarised with Nietzsche myself, and in any case FNS could also be biased. There seems to be room for further debate, that is for sure.